# How can I access hidden/abbreviated stack frames in the Xcode 6 debugger (where did the stack trace abbreviation slider go?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, lldb

In Xcode

In Xcode 6 when the app crashes or when the debugger stopped at a breakpoint we get a stack trace that looks like this in the sidebar:

[image: Xcode 6 debugger stack trace view]

I can click on the different stack frames/methods to jump to the places in the code and inspect the local variables. However, several of the stack frames which belong to the framework are abbreviated.

In Xcode 4 it looked like this:

[image: Xcode 4 debugger stack trace view]

Notice that there was a slider at the bottom. Dragging it to the far right revealed all of the stack frames and made all of them selectable.

I need that functionality in Xcode 6, so my question is any of these:

- **How can I show all stack frames, even the framework ones**
- **How can I access a hidden stack frame to inspect the local variables (e.g. parameters to a method call in a framework)**
- **Where did the slider go and what am I supposed to do without it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slider is gone. Now there is a button in the bottom left-hand corner of the debugger pane saying

> Show only stack frames with debug symbols and between libraries

You have to uncheck it:

[image: Screenshot from XCode]

The buttons are described in [Debug Navigator Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debug_navigator/articles/filtering_threads.html).

Comment: right, I thought I had already clicked on all the buttons in the bottom left, but apparently I didn't. Works as expected, thanks a lot!